# not working on device and not on emulator

Tags: android, parsing

the follwoing code is not working in android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String url = "";
    url = "http://bouncemeinws.cloudapp.net/BounceMeInWebService.asmx/GetAllMerchantNotification";              
    String url1= "http://182.71.82.154/BounceMeInWS/BounceMeInWebService.asmx/GetAllMerchantNotification";      
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {   
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID", "130"));            
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println("status code--->"+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        // HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuffer responseString = new StringBuffer("");
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseString.append(line + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("response is -->" + responseString.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Runtime Errorbody {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}          .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}.version {color: gray;}
.error {margin-bottom: 10px;}.expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *Runtime Error*

**Description:** An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
**Details:** To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
 `<!-- Web.Config Configuration File --> <configuration> <system.web> <customErrors mode="Off"/> </system.web> </configuration>`      
**Notes:** The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.
 `<!-- Web.Config Configuration File ->
 <configuration> <system.web><customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/></system.web> </configuration>`

Comment: Welcome to SO! - "not working"??? come on, we need more details. Exception? LogCat? description of the error?

Comment: Probably ANR due to trying to download stuff from the net in `onCreate(...)` but as Guillaume said - we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Le me guess: you are on Gingerbread or Android 3+

In this case the system just kills your app because you do network IO in the UI thread.

See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703244/100957).